# Color headings according to corresponding button ids in JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have finite number of buttons and headings,

html :

```
<button id = "1">1</button>
<button id = "2">2</button>

<heading id="1">heading1  <button>click</button>  </heading>
<heading id="2">heading2  <button>click</button>  </heading>
```

I want a jquery code such that

1. if I click on a button with id="1", the background color of the button with that id should be turned to yellow
2. if I click on a button which is inside the heading tag of id="1", the button with that id ="1" above, should change its background colour to red.

I just took two buttons and two headings as example, the code should work with any finite number of buttons and headings.

Comment: You cannot have same ids on two or more elements.

Comment: Equally: IDs shouldn't start with / be a number: https://stackoverflow.com/a/79022/2181514

Comment: However, if you just change to `data-id="1"` both of the above comments become irrelevant.

Comment: Have you made an attempt?  Please include what you've tried in the question.  SO is not a code writing service.   In this case `.on("click")` and `.addClass` would suffice, combined with the suggestion of using data.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, `id` should be unique, so you can use classes instead. Try this:

```js
$('button').click(function(){
     var parentTag = $(this).parent().prop("tagName")
     if(parentTag != "HEADING"){ //outer button
          $(`heading.${$(this).attr('class')}`).css('background-color','yellow');
     }else{
          $(`button.${$(this).parent().attr('class')}`).css('color','red');
     }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="1">1</button>
<button class="2">2</button>

<heading class="1">heading1  <button>click</button>  </heading>
<heading class="2">heading2  <button>click</button>  </heading>
```